# how to fix the dispaly of angular ui grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm using Angular UI grid in my application it works good, but the problem in the display of this ui grid..i explain..in my page i have two ui grid, the first one in the first onglet it works good but  when i move to the third onglet where the second ui grid..it doesnt look good..see the picture below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zr3wM.png)

the second ui grid which is bad:
[This dispaly is bad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGXEH.png)

heres the code of each of them:
ui grid1:

```
  $scope.gridOptions = {
        enableFiltering: true,
        enableCellEditOnFocus: false,
        enablePaginationControls: true,
        enableSorting: true,
        enableRowSelection: true,
        enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
        enableColumnResizing: true,
        paginationPageSizes: [10, 12, 15, 18],  //18
        paginationPageSize: 18,             //18


    };
```

ui grid2:

```
 $scope.gridOptions2 = {
        enableFiltering: true,
        enableCellEditOnFocus: false,
        enablePaginationControls: true,
        enableSorting: true,
        enableRowSelection: true,
        enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
        enableColumnResizing: true,
        paginationPageSizes: [10, 12, 15, 18],  //18
        paginationPageSize: 18,             //18


    };
```

Comment: Is there any console error you found

Comment: no..theres no error..i think the problem in the DOM..because when i push any button in the keyboard it displays good..i have no idea why it behavouis like that..

Comment: can you inspect the parent div element may be you missed some css class

Comment: can you check the tr element where your used ng-repeat i think there you missed class